# Redirecting to another component on item click - not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using [react-sidenav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sidenav) package to navigate around different components based on what's clicked. However, this is not working when I try implementing this functionality. Here is my `SideNav` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import SideNav, { Nav, NavIcon, NavText } from 'react-sidenav';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

//specify the base color/background of the parent container if needed
const MySideNav = () => {
    return (
    <div style={{background: '#2c3e50', color: '#FFF', width: 200}}> 
        <SideNav highlightColor='#E91E63' highlightBgColor='#00bcd4' defaultSelected='pos' onItemSelection={ (id, parent) => {
            <Router>
                <Redirect push to={`/${id}`} />
            </Router>
        }}>       
            <Nav id='home'>
                <NavText>Home</NavText>
            </Nav>
            <Nav id='about'>
                <NavText>About</NavText>
            </Nav>
        </SideNav>
    </div>
    )
}
export default MySideNav;
```

I also have this in `Routes.js` file, which I render in `App.js`:

```
<main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
    </Switch>
</main>
```

Then I have separate `About.js` and `Home.js` components, which I have already imported in `Routes.js`. When I click individual items in the sidebar, I am not able to redirect to any other components.
I can't figure out where I am going wrong since I am a beginner in React. Could someone please assist me with this? That would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE**
When using `withRR4`, the redirection is being done in the url bar, but the target components are not being rendered. Here's is my code for this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, withRR4 , NavIcon, NavText } from 'react-sidenav';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
const SideNav = withRR4();    
    //specify the base color/background of the parent container if needed
    const MySideNav = () => {
        return (
        <div style={{background: '#2c3e50', color: '#FFF', width: 200}}> 
        <Router>
            <SideNav highlightColor='#E91E63' highlightBgColor='#00bcd4'>       
                <Nav id='home'>
                    <NavText>Home</NavText>
                </Nav>
                <Nav id='about'>
                    <NavText>About</NavText>
                </Nav>
            </SideNav>
        </div>
        )
    }
    export default MySideNav;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use withRR4 as explained in the Docs here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sidenav#react-router-4-integration

**EDIT**
You need to import the `<Route/>` 's you want to use inside the `<Router />`

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRR4, Nav, NavText } from 'react-sidenav';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const SideNav = withRR4();

class MySideNav  extends React.Component {
    renderHome = () => {
        return <div>Home</div>;
    };

    renderAbout = () => {
        return <div>About</div>;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div style={{ background: '#2c3e50', color: '#FFF', width: 200 }}>
                    <SideNav default='home' highlightColor='#E91E63' highlightBgColor='#00bcd4'>
                        <Nav id='home'>
                            <NavText> Home </NavText>
                        </Nav>
                        <Nav id='about'>
                            <NavText> About </NavText>
                        </Nav>
                    </SideNav>
                </div>
                <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
                    <Route exact path="/" render={this.renderHome}/>
                    <Route path="/home" render={this.renderHome}/>
                    <Route path="/about" render={this.renderAbout}/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

- I am not 100% if you must put these Routes here, can you test it out for me?

Comment: Thanks for this, I overlooked it in the documentation. However, when I try using `withRR4`, I can see the redirection being done in the url bar, but the target components are not being rendered at all. I have updated my question with the code for this. Would you be able to help me out with this? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah no problem, I will try to reproduce your problem :)

Comment: @Jspake I edited the answer, this should be work now :) 
Also, ifound that you didnt close Router component on the bottom of your component. You close with a < /div > instead of < /Router >

Comment: Since the `Router` needs to have a single child element, I had to wrap the two `<div>`s into a single one. The rest worked perfectly! Thanks so much :)